# Blazor WASM - Timer stops after some time

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I have this simple timer in my blazor client (wasm) app:

```
 var t2 = new Timer(async (object? state) =>
            {
                await UpdateCurrentConsumptionData();
            },null,3000,5000);
```

Calling

```
private async Task UpdateCurrentConsumptionData()
        {
            var http = httpClientSelector!.GetNoAuthHttpClient();
            currentPowerConsumptionData = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<Shared.Models.GenericInfluxDatapoint>(Config.URL_GET_DASHBOARD_CURRENT_POWER_CONSUMPTION_DATA);
            StateHasChanged();          
           
        }
```

Which works, but stops after some time.. seems random, 9-13 times my timer runs, then stops.
What am i missing? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should make the timer variable a class variable (field) not a `var`. When you leave the routine where the timer was created it will be disposed.

Comment: D'oh .. thanks - that was the problem!

Comment: You also need to implement IDisposable, see the linked duplicate.